# what is adapter in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, reactjs-testutils

Any documentation on what's the purpose of `adapter` in `enzyme` testing library.

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-adapter-react-16

Comment: I looked over there, all they mentioned was how to install and what version to be installed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Any documentation on what's the purpose of `adapter` in `enzyme` testing library.

The closest it gets is to say ["You will need to install enzyme along with an Adapter corresponding to the version of react (or other UI Component library) you are using"](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/#installation).

The docs mostly just explain how to configure an `adapter` and don't really talk about its purpose.

---

> what is adapter in enzyme

---

**Short version**

The `enzyme` API is the same regardless of the version of `React` you are using, but how `React` renders and interacts with what is rendered changes depending on the `React` version.

The `adapter` abstracts away anything that changes based on the `React` version so the core `enzyme` code can stay the same.

---

**Detailed version**

`mount` and `shallow` are both [exported from `enzyme`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/index.js#L12-L13).  Let's focus on `mount`.

`mount` is a function that [just returns a new `ReactWrapper`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/mount.js#L10).

`ReactWrapper` provides the familiar wrapper object with [`instance`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L222), [`setState`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L320), [`find`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L505), etc.

The implementation of all of those functions is the same regardless of which version of `React` you are using...

...but because `React` itself has changed over the years *any implementation details that change based on the `React` version* are abstracted away with an adapter.

The adapter is retrieved by calling [`getAdapter`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L18) and the first time it is used is to [validate the nodes passed to `mount`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L104-L107), and then to [create the `renderer` to actually render the nodes](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L110-L112).

For `enzyme-adapter-react-16.3` that call to [`createRenderer`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L110) gets [routed to `this.createMountRenderer`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16.3/src/ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js#L441) and within `createMountRenderer` you can see [the familiar `ReactDOM.render` call where what you passed is actually rendered using `React` v16 syntax](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme-adapter-react-16.3/src/ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js#L288).

---

Searching for `getAdapter` within [ReactWrapper.js](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js) shows everywhere that the `adapter` is used to abstract away functionality that changes based on the `React` version while using `mount`...

...and searching for `getAdapter` within [ShallowWrapper.js](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/df7ad40a088b0f1cee083e007b07793741d6ce59/packages/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js) shows everywhere that `adapter` is used to abstract away functionality that changes based on the `React` version while using `shallow`.

Comment: Would it be valid to say that adapter here is like the 'driver softwares' that we install in Windows. Let's say if I have a new external device so my OS wouldn't know how to interact with that device unless proper drivers of that device are installed in the OS?

Also could you please give a real time example of what would happen if enzyme adapter isn't present OR is outdated with respect to the corresponding version of it's UI library/framework?