# what's the relationship between enzyme and adapter

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm a beginner in React, just a question on the use of adapter.
I saw some code like this:

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
});
```

I was told that an adapter can reduce the core libraries, but how does adapters  actually works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is adapter in enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344422/what-is-adapter-in-enzyme)

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345750/10149510) goes over what the adapter is for and has links into the source code to show how Enzyme uses the adapter